# Is SSRS 2008 supports exporting to .xlsx format instead of .xls

Tags: excel, ssrs-2008

I have MS Office 2007 installed in my machine. when i export SSRS 2008 report to Excel, i need to save in .xlsx format rather than .xls format. what settings we need to do.

pls give me the solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

2008 only supports xls.

You will need to either write a [rendering extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153624%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) or purchasing a 3rd party component from a company like [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/)

Comment: you are right Nishant, SSRS 2012 provides .xlsx file format out of the box

Comment: SQL reporting services from SQL 2012 supports XLSX.